# Aouth 2 Web Service Call from Mule

Tags: mule

I am trying to call the web service from mule which requires the access token for authorization. We have to generate the token from token URL and then we need to pass that token in Authorization to get the result from the web service.

I have written the Java Program to generate the access token, and it is working fine. But when i am trying to access the API with the generated Token it is giving the below error:

> Error sending HTTP request.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post and add the concrete error description. The one you gave is too unspecific. You need to enable debugging in your tool. Also add the code you wrote so far.

Comment: @sumi jain Can you add more from error/exception stacktrace?

Comment: This is the only exception we are getting. On other exception.